# Is it bad if I can't do legs in the gym?

Tags: injury, legs

I still work calves but I am unable to do legs due to a forn facia in my right quad. Cheers.

Comment: Why would it be bad if you're legitimately injured?

Comment: I probably said the question in a bad way. I met is it a major set back to my progress? Or is it ok to only work your upper body and calves.

Comment: Well, yes, it is going to be a small setback. On the other hand, if you injured it in training, you may be pushing slightly to hard.

Comment: I think I did it playing rugby. I can walk and run and do things fine but when I do even a light leg workout, the facia tear gets bigger. When I flex my quad, the muscle comes out of the facia and produces a lump about the size of a golf ball.

Comment: @user3750, I searched this site for "training when injured" and found a bunch of useful answers, see the search box in http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: This helped a lot. Thankyou for the help!

Answer (score 3):

There are times in our training where you have to train around injuries.  This is not bad, just a fact of life.  Will you lose some strength and progress? Yes.  There's no way around that.  However, a small injury will become a big one one if you don't let your body heal.

I recommend letting your torn facia heal.  You can focus on other things at the moment, or just rest.  Follow the instructions your doctor gave you, and when you are given the green light, ramp your training up gently.

If you know what caused the injury to begin with, see if you can do anything to prevent it from happening again.  If it was due to bad technique, fix your technique.  If it was due to the violence of the sport (which is quite possible with rugby), see if you can refine your technique that takes that opportunity away from your opponent.